# xslt from siblings to nested elements

Tags: xslt

I'm an xslt beginner and I am really struggling with the following task:

From this xml (NB I don't know the number of children nodes of the parent node):

```
<parent>
  <element_a id="e1"/>
  <element_b id="e2"/>
  <element_a id="e3"/>
  <element_c id="e4"/>
  ...
</parent>
```

I need to get this xml:

```
<e1>
  <e2>
    <e3>
      <e4>
        ...
      </e4>
    </e3>
  </e2>
</e1>
```

I've tried several times, but I cannot get a correct output. Here is one attempt:

```
<xsl:template name="test">
    <xsl:element name="{@id}">
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:call-template name="test"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="parent">
    <parent>
        <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <xsl:for-each select=".">
                <xsl:element name="{@id}">
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:call-template name="test"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </parent>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Even if it isn't right, can you still include the XSLT you have tried in your question please? You might not actually be that far off from a solution. Thank you!

Comment: One problem with your attempt is that your `<xsl:call-template name="test"/>` instruction in your named template doesn't actually change the current element, so it'll recursive infinitely on the same element.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="parent">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parent/*">
      <xsl:element name="{@id}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously you'll need to add some specific handling of other elements, but hopefully this should point you in the direction of the right structure.

It works by having the parent element process only it's first child, then having every child of a parent create an element with a name matching the `id` attribute, then processing the next element as a new child, recursively.

One gotcha with this- if an `id` attribute ever contains a value that is not a valid element name, the transformation will fail.

Comment: Thank you so much! I now understand.

Comment: For reference, this technique is sometimes called "sibling recursion": the idea is that the template rule for an element applies-templates to the immediately following sibling, whose matching template rule then does the same thing, recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative in XSLT 3 that uses `for-each-group` in a recursive function to try to implement the nesting in a way that allows streaming with processors like Saxon 9.8 EE or normal XSLT 3 processing in other editions of Saxon 9.8 or in Altova (which doens't support streaming):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" streamable="yes"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:nest" as="node()*" streamability="absorbing">
        <xsl:param name="nodes" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$nodes" group-adjacent="true()">
            <xsl:element name="{@id}">
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:nest(tail(current-group()))"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="parent">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:nest(*)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As the sibling navigation is not possible with streaming I think this is one way to process the siblings recursively with streaming.